# Safety factor in aircraft design

Tags: safety

How can a plane withstand the safety factor of 2.5?

Comment: Are you asking about safety factor or load factor?

Comment: I'm asking about safety factor

Answer (score 5):

Safety factor describes the structural capacity of a system beyond the expected loads or actual loads. So, safety factor gives how much the system is stronger (i.e. how much load it can take before failure) compared to the expected load on the system.

$ Safety \ Factor = \frac {Maximum \ load \ before \ failure}{Design \ load}$

Design load, sometimes called the limit load is the maximum amount of load the part is expected to face in service. In aviation, the FAR Part 25 deals with safety in §25.303   Factor of safety, which says,

> Unless otherwise specified, a factor of safety of 1.5 must be applied to the prescribed limit load which are considered external loads on the structure. When a loading condition is prescribed in terms of ultimate loads, a factor of safety need not be applied unless otherwise specified.

As can be seen, the safety factor is the structural load for which the system has been *designed*, not a load that *actually acts on the system*. The main reasons for having a factor of safety are,

- Loads may be high in certain unexpected situations (like emergency)
- The structure may undergo wear and tear and my degrade over time.
- The structure may be loaded beyond the expected loads inadvertently.

Except in unusual circumstances, the aircraft *will not to withstand* any safety factor; rather is is *designed to withstand* safety factor times the maximum expected load. The figure of 2.5 is too high for safety factor in aviation and has not been used in any aircraft to the best of my knowledge due to the exorbitant weight penalty involved.

The term used for withstanding of load is called *load factor*, which is given as the ratio of aerodynamic load perpendicular to longitudinal axis to the aircraft weight.